# converting image to grayscale using arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, nested, nested-loops, grayscale

Here is my code. Im not sure why this isnt working. It says index exceed matrix dimensions. and then it says Error in grayscale1 (line 7) avg=mean(pic(col, row, :));
I want to use the function by inputing     image(grayscale1(imagename))

Also here is my prompt Write a function named “grayscale1.m” that receives a filename for an image file and returns a 3-D array with a grayscale version of the image. It should work for images of any size. Your solution should use nested loops to set the value of every pixel.

```
function grayscale1(picture)
pic = imread(picture);
[r c] = size(pic); 
    for row = 1:r 
         for col = 1:c 
             avg=mean(pic(row, col, :));
               pic(row,col,:)=avg;
          end
    end   
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

If `pic` is a 3-dimensional array, then this:

```
[r c] = size(pic);
```

will give you size of 1st dimension in `r` and **multiplication** of sizes of 2nd and 3rd dimensions in `c`. It's probably not what you want. So you should do:

```
[r c ignore] = size(pic);
```

or

```
r = size(pic, 1);
c = size(pic, 2);
```